# Are there things you cannot put into a list?

Tags: r, list

Are there things you **cannot** put into an R list - if so, or not how come? Are there things you **should not** put into a list for particular hard reasons - speed, efficiency, memory footprint, error proneness, ...?

So far I have not found anything that cannot be put into a list (vectors, data.frames, environments, ...) but I am not sure and I would like to get a somewhat deeper understanding.

Comment: Lists can contain elements of any type, including lists.  I don't know of any general advice regarding what it is and isn't good practice to put into lists; I would think it would depend on the purpose to which you are putting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Anything can be put into a list** and it is a widely used practice in R to return lists when multiple return values of completely different types are required. For example, consider the return value of the linear model function `lm`, returning an object of class `lm`, which is nothing else than a list with an additional class assignment. It contains numerical vectors like `coefficients` and a `call` object containing the original call of the function - an example for completely different data types. Consider `str(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris))` to see how many different data types are returned by `lm`.

**What should not be in lists: Data points of all kind having the same type.** These are especially vectors of `numeric`, `character` and `logic` values. Whenever possible, use vectors and not lists as operations on vectors are usually much faster. Many data types overload the `c` operator and offer vector-like data types, e.g. `POSIXct` for timestamps:

```
> str(c(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 60))
 POSIXct[1:2], format: "2016-07-11 11:58:45" "2016-07-11 11:59:45"
```

These vector-like objects should be preferred instead of a `list` of such values.